# From trait - How to implement it from a slice

Tags: rust

Looking at the documentation for the [trait `std::convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html), it says:

> Used to do value-to-value conversions while consuming the input value.

To me, and looking at the `fn from(T) -> Self` signature, it sounds like the function takes ownership of the argument.

How can e.g. `String` implement the `From<&str>` trait? It cannot take ownership from the shared reference.

I want to implement a "viewer" structure; something that doesn't take ownership: Say a `&[u8]` represents my binary data; the first byte is my "data id".

```
struct DataView {
    id: u8,
    data: &[u8],
}
```

Then I would like to be able to do something like:

```
impl From<&[u8]> for DataView {
    fn from(buffer: &[u8]) -> DataView {
        DataView {
            id: buffer[0],
            data: &buffer[1..],
        }
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible? Does such a structure make sense if I am only interested in "viewing"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that without taking ownership. But first, every stuct that contains a reference needs a lifetime to assert, that it doesn't exist passt the scope of the data it references:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct DataView<'a> {
    id: u8,
    data: &'a [u8],
}
```

Now we can implement the From trait the following manner:

```
impl<'a> From<&'a [u8]> for DataView<'a> {
    fn from(arg: &'a [u8]) -> Self {
        let id = arg[0];
        let data = &arg[1..];
        Self { id, data }
    }
}
```

Note that we are explicitly asserting that the referenced argmument has the same lifetime as the DataView object.
Now we can do:

```
fn main() {
    let arg: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3, 4, 6];

    let view = DataView::from(arg);
    println!("{:?}", view);
}
```

Comment: I haven't gotten far enough in The Book to read about lifetimes, but this implies that the documentation of the trait is very misleading. Do you agree? Or how should I interpret the "Used to do value-to-value conversions while consuming the input value" when dealing with references for this trait?

Comment: Shared references are `Copy`, just like, e.g. primitive integer types (`i64`, etc.). You can not "take ownership" of a `Copy` value, it is automatically, trivially copied when you use it.

Comment: In rust references are full fledged types. In our case the type is the generic lifetime reference &'a [u8]